# Preciso contar quantos elementos repetidos tem em uma matriz

Tags: python, matriz, for, while

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
def conta_numero(numero,matriz):
cont=0
soma=0
while cont<len(matriz):
 for n in matriz[cont]:
     if n==numero:
        soma+=matriz[cont].count(n)
 cont+=1
return soma 


conta_numero(9,[[9,4,9,8,8]])
```

De doze testes, esse foi o único que não passou, e eu não entendo o porquê, pois ao invés de retornar o valor 2, está retornando o valor 4. Poderiam me ajudar?

Obs: estou querendo saber quantas vezes o número 9 se repete na matriz.

Comment: Você não estaria tentando fazer isso https://ideone.com/RAuh2j

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Está dando 4 por conta dessa função count.

```
matrix[0].count(9) #ira retornar 2
```

E como n passa pelo 9 duas vezes, logo ira somar 2+2

Uma solução seria simplesmente somar 1:

```html
def conta_numero(numero,matriz):
    cont=0
    soma=0
    while cont<len(matriz):
     for n in matriz[cont]:
         if n==numero:
            soma+=1
     cont+=1
    return soma 


print ( conta_numero(9,[[9,4,9,8,8]])  )
```

Comment: Nossa, me ajudou muito. Obrigada 